# Retrofit call contains error Required retrofit2.Call, found void

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, retrofit2, android-studio-3.0

Hello I recently started `retrofit` While implementing the code im getting this error

```
Incompatible types. 
Required: retrofit2.Call <java.util.List<com.my.package.Youtube.YoutubePost>>
Found: void
```

I was trying to get YouTube channel playlist using `Youtube v3 API`

This is my code for the same

**YoutubeActivity**

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(AppConstant.API_YT_BASE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    YoutubeApiInterface youtubeApiInterface = retrofit.create(YoutubeApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<YoutubePost>> call = youtubeApiInterface.getPlayList().enqueue(new Callback<List<YoutubePost>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<YoutubePost>> call, Response<List<YoutubePost>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<YoutubePost>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
```

**YoutubePost**

```
public class YoutubePost implements Parcelable {
    @SerializedName("items")
    private List<YoutubeItems> ytItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private String nextPageToken;

    public List<YoutubeItems> getYtItems() {
        return ytItems;
    }

    public String getNextPageToken() {
        return nextPageToken;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(ytItems);
        dest.writeString(nextPageToken);
    }

    protected YoutubePost(Parcel in) {
        ytItems = in.readParcelable(YoutubeItems.class.getClassLoader());
        nextPageToken = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<YoutubePost> CREATOR = new Creator<YoutubePost>() {
        @Override
        public YoutubePost createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new YoutubePost(source);
        }

        @Override
        public YoutubePost[] newArray(int size) {
            return new YoutubePost[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Screenshot of error message attached below

[image]

Comment: Please share your youtubeApiInterface codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you, to modify the *getPlayList* method a little bit, to *return with a Call*, then break the lines.
Without your YoutubeApiInterface this is all I got.

```
Call<List<YoutubePost>> call = youtubeApiInterface.getPlayList();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<YoutubePost>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<YoutubePost>> call, Response<List<YoutubePost>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            } else {

            }
        }.

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<YoutubePost>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
```

By this you won't have a type problem, because the **call** itself will be modified, during the enqueue.